# Windows 8 'net use' no longer works

Tags: networking, windows-8

The `net use` was able to show the source of my network drives, to up to Win 7.
Now under Windows 8:

```
D:\>net use
New connections will be remembered.

There are no entries in the list.
```

So how can I get a list of the source of my network drives under Windows 8?

**EDIT:** I'm not talking about the network drives manually added by `net use` itself, but network drives assigned to me when I log in into my domain. In my company, I have win7 and win8 environments. Same account, same policy, only different is the host that I remote in, and the result of `net use` do behave differently. On win7, I can see the mapping of my X: Y: and Z: network drives, whereas in Win8, I only get "There are no entries in the list", even though I do have my X: Y: and Z: network drives.

Thanks

Comment: How exactly are they being applied by GP?  Login scripting?  computer startup scripting?  Group Policy Preference mappings?

Comment: Is there any way that I can tell? I'm just a normal domain user BTW.

Answer (score 6):

`Net Use` under Windows 8 works exactly as it did in Windows 7 (and Vista, and XP, etc.).

You have no Net Use entries set (aka: nothing "mapped"), hence it tells you "There are no entries in the list".

You may be running into a user vs. administrator context confusion though.  If you map the drives as your user, and then start a command prompt "As Administrator", then it's a different user context, so the command-line doesn't have the mapped drives.

This too is exactly how Windows 7 worked.

Comment: It may appear the same to you in your environment, but `net use` definitely behaves differently in my environment. Can you see your normal network drives and mapping in your `net use` output from your win7? If not, your win7 environment is different then mine then.

Comment: Passed my 5min, In my Corp, I have win7 and win8 environments and they do behave differently.

Comment: @xpt "Can you see your normal network drives and mapping": I'm not sure what you mean by "normal network drives".  In both Window s7 and 8, if I have any network drives mapped then Net Use shows me them.  Perhaps you could edit your original question to further explain exactly what you expect to see, and include how you are connecting/mapping to the shares?

Comment: original question edited.

Answer (score 1):

I use the enable linked connections setting so that my as "administrator" consoles can see my user mapped drives while under the administrator token.  The problem is the split-token in UAC is prevented from seeing the drives for your 'safety'.

Here is the fix, it runs from Powershell.

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" -Name "EnableLinkedConnections" -Value 1 -PropertyType "DWord"
#
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844140%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks. doesn't work for my case though.