# Disconnect from smb share with powershell on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, powershell, network-shares, samba

I'm trying to disconnect a smb share with a Powershell command in Windows 10:

```
net use * /delete
```

However, this command does not work, because the share is not shown with `net use`. The output is `There are no entries in the list.`

`Get-SmbConnection` is showing the results I'd expect,

```
ServerName ShareName UserName  Credential Dialect NumOpens
---------- --------- --------  ---------- ------- --------
FILESERVER extra     xxx\xxxxx xxx\xxxxx  3.0     1
FILESERVER home      xxx\xxxxx xxx\xxxxx  3.0     1
FILESERVER IPC$      xxx\xxxxx xxx\xxxxx  3.0     0
FILESERVER public    xxx\xxxxx xxx\xxxxx  3.0     2
```

But I do not know how to disconnect a share with this information.

The reason for my question: I want to write a batch script which disconnects all network shares from a PC after log off (e.g. Win+L keys). On Windows 7 and 8 I use the mentioned `net use * /delete` command, which does not work on Windows 10, as shown above.
The SMB shares are accessible with the GUI (Explorer -> Network ...) and I can save, change and delete files on them. But the share is not mapped to a drive letter.

---

Following is a bit output for stuff that does **not** help, but it seems my question is still not clear enough:

`Get-SmbConnection` : see above, I want to close these!

`Get-SmbSession` : No output.

`Get-SmbMapping` : No output.

`Get-SmbShare` :

```
Name   ScopeName Path                              Description
----   --------- ----                              -----------
ADMIN$ *         C:\WINDOWS                        Remoteverwaltung
C$     *         C:\                               Standardfreigabe
IPC$   *                                           Remote-IPC
print$ *         C:\WINDOWS\system32\spool\drivers Druckertreiber
```

Comment: In the future, if a command you expect to work is not working, add any error message or mention that there are none to your post.

Comment: Thank you for your edit and corrections, I clarified it a bit more, added the "error messages" and a bit background information.

Comment: It seems to me that this [windows-8-net-use-no-longer-works](https://superuser.com/questions/695035/windows-8-net-use-no-longer-works#695039) is exactly the same problem

Comment: 3 years old and still a open question (for me). I found this thread https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ffd8eb2a-9c67-4ab4-adcb-14cfd6a20b43/how-to-close-smb-connection-to-remote-share where a couple of users have the same problem as me, but without a solution

Comment: I have this question too, and just read that [technet link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ffd8eb2a-9c67-4ab4-adcb-14cfd6a20b43/how-to-close-smb-connection-to-remote-share). Wow that was a completely arrogant set of useless answers!

Comment: @WiringHarness yes, wow! astonishing lack of understanding and dismissal from that technet forum. So bad it's somewhat entertaining to read . [Archived here](https://archive.ph/3MhtX).

Comment: For text search matching: I encountered this problem with dialog error
"_The network folder specified is currently mapped using a different user name and password. To connect using a different user name and password, first disconnect any existing mappings to this network share._".
I cannot close the SMB connection for the same reasons stated in this Question. Seems like a big hole in the PowerShell SMB cmdlet API.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`Remove-SmbMapping`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635718.aspx).  Assuming you're on the client, it looks like this is the one you want to use.  You can probably pipe results from `Get-SMBConnection` to `Remove-SmbMapping`

Comment: Yes, I am on the client. I added the results from 'Get-SmbMapping' in my question. I can add one and can remove one but I cannot remove the open SmbConnections

Comment: `Get-SMBConnection` shows the credential of the account that connected the share.  Are you using the same account to disconnect it?  Also, check `Remove-SmbMapping` for a `-Force` switch.  Sounds like MS has changed the way mapping works and the new best practice has not made it to the public at large.

Comment: Yes, I run `Get-SmbConnection` as admin and it shows the right user name and credential (in the form machinename\username, not the admin account). Yes it seems that unmapped smb works different in smb3. In earlier versions I could use `net use * /d` to "remove" the connection and lock in again with user credentials, this does not work any more.

Comment: You have no shares as client, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

`net use` is for *[mapped drives and printers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/gg651155(v=ws.11))*. Even the asterisk is just a shortcut for a drive letter:

> `<DeviceName>`
>
> Assigns a name to connect to the resource or specifies the device to be disconnected. There are two kinds of device names: disk drives (that is, D: through Z:) and printers (that is, LPT1: through LPT3:). Type an asterisk (*) instead of a specific device name to assign the next available device name.

Mapped drives are per-user session. They no longer exist when you log out.

`Get-SmbConnection` really is [all smb connections](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/smbshare/get-smbconnection?view=win10-ps), including using different credentials and sessions:

> The Get-SmbConnection cmdlet retrieves the connections established from the Server Message Block (SMB) client to the SMB servers. Users can connect to an SMB share using credentials different than the associated logon credentials so that there will be a connection listed per share per user logon per credential used

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but did you see that this is the opposite to what I experienced under win7? I could close the connections with net use /d *. Also the first link yields a 404

Comment: Do you have an idea how I can close "unmapped" smb connections?

Comment: I fixed the link

Comment: @dice My understanding is this type of connection is only for things that are in _active use_. Close the file, the connection ends. Log, so the file program using the file closes, and the connection will catch up quickly on it's own.