# Switch users on network shares

Tags: windows-10, nas, shared-folders, privileges

I have 2 issues that are driving me crazy. I have a NAS on my home network, to prevent ransomware attack I created two accounts: `user_ro` and `user_rw` that can respectfully only read, or read+write. Let's assume my devices are W10 workstation up-to-date.

### NAS Security

Theoretically, I would like my NAS to always be accessible using `user_ro` account. I don't mind if the creds are stored, I want convenience.

However, if I need to write something onto the NAS, I would like to be able to ***easily*** and ***temporarily*** "elevate" my privilege to use `user_rw` account. (I know it's not really elevation like with 'sudo', but you get the gist of it.)

So far, I could not find a way to do that using W10 features.

- **Is there a way to access a shared drive using 1 account and easily + temporarily switch to another account for write purpose?**

Because I did not find a way, I decided that the best course of action was to simply disconnect/reconnect using another account. Which leds to my 2nd issue. If I forget to switch to `user_ro` and I get hit by a ransomware, I'm done however...

### How to switch account on a shared drive?

I'm connected to my NAS using `user_ro` but I want to copy a file. I need to switch to `user_rw`. To put it simply, I can't find a way to do that.

I searched and all the answers are about using `net use` to delete mounted shared drive. However, there's no entry, so nothing to delete.

I can also delete the creds from the Credential Manager, but it doesn't disconnect me.

I cannot do some `right-click > disconnect` as there's no such options

On the WExplorer window, I don't find an option to switch users nor disconnect.

- **How can I disconnect from a shared drive?**

Comment: If your NAS resolves using its hostname - that will be considered a separate NAS / Server when you connect to it using its IP address. So for example - connecting to \\myNas\share vs \\ip.addr.of.myNas\share - you can use different account for them.

Comment: @Darius: thanks, this allows me to access it as another user. However, I still cannot logout, if I close the WExplorer window and try to access it again, i'm automatically authenticated even though I asked it to not remember my credentials.

Comment: Can I confirm 1 thing - do you have it as a "Mapped Network Drive" or it is simply an entry in "Network Location"? If its Network Locations - you right click and choose Delete. If its a Mapped Network drive - then Right-Click and choose Disconnect should exist.

Comment: Fully disconnect from shares by removing/not saving the passphrase credential for the share. Does [Controlled Folder Access](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/controlled-folders?view=o365-worldwide) not work for shares _(it's the easiest way to prevent Ransomware access in Win10)_? If CFA doesn't, the best way to prevent Ransomware data loss is to either maintain an air-gapped backup _(cycled every x days)_ or capture encrypted backups of the data daily, easily done via `tar` or `robocopy` to only copy over changed data, using `7zip` to encrypt.

Comment: "How can I disconnect from a shared drive?" As far as I know this is only possible if you connect to the drive a certain way (look e.g. here https://windowsreport.com/map-network-drive-windows-10/) But I have not found a way to disconnect if the network drive is not mapped: https://superuser.com/questions/1129183/disconnect-from-smb-share-with-powershell-on-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

To connect to one network drive as two different users, assuming the target drive resolves using its hostname [`\\MyServer\Share`], you can map it twice using its hostname and IP address; Windows will think you are connecting to two different servers, even though it resolves to the same address:

- `\\MyServer\Share`
- `\\ip.address.of.myServer\share`

Comment: Thank you, it allows me to connect to the share with 2 different accounts. However, if I cannot disconnect the connection with the most privileged account this is of no use. Deleting the share does not disconnect me