# Force refresh on Windows' client side when the Samba server gives an outdated file?

Tags: network-shares, samba, file-sharing, smb, shared-folders

Let's say that there is a file F on a Linux system EXT4. F is shared through Samba. First, I open F on a Windows client. Now, a process on the Linux system updates F. But the Windows client still sees the old version of F. Closing F and opening it again on the Windows client, or terminating the Linux process that updated the file, does not seem to refresh the file (get the latest file on the Linux system). The only thing that worked was restarting the Samba service. Is there any other way to refresh a directory/file on the Windows client, without restarting the Samba service?

Comment: Which SMB version is being used? Are "kernel oplocks" enabled on the Samba side?

Comment: @user1686 smb.cfg only has min =smb2, so I guess the version is smb3, or whatever the default version used in Windows 11. I do not see "oplocks" in smb.cfg, and I have not manually change that setting, so it probably is the default value for that. `samba --version Version 4.16.2`

Answer (score 0):

This [existing answer](https://superuser.com/a/1130029/203857) for another question worked. In short, in PowerShell  run `Remove-SmbMapping`, and try to re-open the file.